# Writing to a NamedTemporaryFile does nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

The following Python code does not write "This is not getting written" into my NamedTemporaryFile.

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w') as f:
    f.write("This is not getting written")
    print("Place a break point here.")
```

I place a break point on the print statement (so the file doesn't get deleted) and attempt to cat the file that is being referenced by `f.name`, but it comes up empty.

Using Python3.5

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You didn't flush your output.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Well that did it. Quite odd, I've never had to flush output to any other file-like object before. Is this a special case for Python 3.5?

Comment: Sounds like you've never tried to read a file between writing and closing before.

Comment: None of this is specific to Python 3.5 or to NamedTemporaryFile.